# Enable trust proxy on Next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

On Express.js, you do

```
// see https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html
app.set('trust proxy', 1);
```

I am trying to add a ratelimit, and it's a Express middleware, which Next.js support, but I need to allow proxies on my Next.js app. I have tried googling but I haven't found anything helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Express.js *trust proxy* sets the `req.protocol` to match the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header (see the [source](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/353348a83e6874db7ded27102e91e7b6cad7e89c/lib/request.js#L306-L324)). As far as I know Next.js doesn't have a similar *trust proxy* setting. Also the middleware of the current (v12.2) Next.JS version doesn't allow the modification of the request object, so it's not possible to create a custom trust proxy middleware.

One solution is to create a wrapper around the Express middleware. This wrapper adds the `protocol` property to the request before passing it to Express middleware, and that added property should be sufficient for the ratelimit middleware to know it's behind a secure connection.

```js
// middleware.js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function middleware(req) {
  const res = NextResponse.next();
  req.protocol = req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] ?? 'http';
  await runExpressMiddleware(req, res, exampleMiddleware);
  return res;
}

function runExpressMiddleware(req, res, middlewareFn) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    middlewareFn(req, res, (result) => {
      if (result instanceof Error) {
        return reject(result);
      }
      return resolve(result);
    });
  });
}

function exampleMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.protocol); // Value of x-forwarded-proto header or http
  next();
}
```